# Access cookies in angularJs service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

I can succesfully access cookies on my controller like this.

```
angular.module('mobbr', [ 'ngCookies' ]).    

function RegisterCtrl($scope, $cookies) { }
```

But whenever i try to use cookies in a service like this.

```
angular.module('mobbr.services', []);
angular.module('mobbr.services').factory('currentUser', [ 'ngCookies', function ($cookies) {}]);
```

I get the following error: ngCookiesProvider <- ngCookies <- currentUser.

Any thoughts on why this won't work and how i should initialize a service with acces to cookies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what my code for something similar looks like:

```
angular.module('app.MyData', ['ngResource','ngCookies']).
    factory('MyService', function($resource, $http, $cookies) {
        ...
    })
```

Comment: The key is 'ngCookies' in app.js and then $cookies in controllers/services.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
module.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookies',
        function($scope, $cookies) {
             ...........
         }
    ]);
```

Instead of using `ngCookies` I am using `$cookies`. I looked at this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) but somehow it was throwing error `Unknown provider: ngCookiesProvider <- ngCookies`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to this question. Question is about accessing $cookies in a service, not in a controller.

Comment: @lin: Your point is partially valid. But I think if it works in Controller, it will work in service is well. I added my answer hoping it will help some user whos is facing similar issue as mine.

Comment: Nope, you cannot use all abstracts in a service, directive, controller, factory, etc.